# Where will the entered location be saved?

Tags: html

I'm building a website, and I want to enable images to be uploaded only to the camera via mobile.

`<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

So I used the following code:
Here's what I'm curious about:
When you use this code, isn't the image saved to your mobile phone? I should not be stored on your phone for security reasons. If it cannot be saved, where are the photos taken with the phone's camera saved and transmitted to the server?

Second, I'm curious about the file name. The file name seems to be a temporary random number with a temporary pattern applied. What does this mean?
Thanks

Comment: This is not uploading to a camera via mobile.  If you view this web page on a mobile phone and the user clicks the button, the camera will take a picture and send it to whatever web server handles the `<form>`.  The image is not saved anywhere.  It's exactly like sending a file from your phone, except instead of a file from disk, it grabs an image from the camera.

Comment: *"When the `capture` attribute is specified, the user agent MUST NOT save the captured media to any data storage, local or remote. "* - from [the w3c standard](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/#dfn-capture). most likely browsers would temporarily store them in memory.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]